# What is wrong with this code to make it miss removing the last html file from the list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7 on mint. trying to remove all HTML or XML files from a list of files from a directory.  When the file name is all numbers, it will only remove 3 of the four non image files...and in the final printing, leaves me with 00335786.html still in the list.

```
pdfImages = os.listdir(pdfLocalPath + "/html/")
    for item in pdfImages:##FIX TODO
        print "ITEM = " + item
        if str(item).endswith(("xml", "html")):
            print "FOUND FILE = " + item
            pdfImages.remove(item)

    print "pdfImages = " + str(pdfImages)
```

using this list of files

```
['00335786_ind.html', '00335786.html', '00335786-3_1.png', '00335786-1_1.png', '00335786.xml', '00335786-5_1.png', '00335786-2_1.png', '00335786s.html', '00335786-4_1.png']
```

I get this in return

```
['00335786.html', '00335786-3_1.png', '00335786-1_1.png', '00335786-5_1.png', '00335786-2_1.png', '00335786-4_1.png']
```

i have tried with a different file, in it's own directory

```
['p6004-53_2.png', 'p6004-141_2.png', 'p6004-96_1.jpg', 'p6004-178_2.jpg', 'p6004-133_4.jpg', 'p6004-96_2.jpg', 'p6004-211_1.jpg', 'p6004-220_1.jpg', 'p6004-142_1.png', 'p6004-135_4.jpg', 'p6004-189_1.jpg', 'p6004-192_1.jpg', 'p6004-225_1.jpg', 'p6004-146_1.jpg', 'p6004-150_1.jpg', 'p6004-133_1.jpg', 'p6004-54_2.jpg', 'p6004-227_1.jpg', 'p6004-39_1.jpg', 'p6004-149_1.jpg', 'p6004-161_1.jpg', 'p6004-154_1.jpg', 'p6004-217_1.jpg', 'p6004-219_1.jpg', 'p6004-54_1.png', 'p6004-17_1.jpg', 'p6004-174_1.jpg', 'p6004-1_1.jpg', 'p6004-142_2.png', 'p6004-214_2.jpg', 'p6004-51_2.png', 'p6004-243_5.png', 'p6004-208_1.jpg', 'p6004-55_1.jpg', 'p6004-197_1.jpg', 'p6004-170_2.jpg', 'p6004-214_1.jpg', 'p6004-46_1.jpg', 'p6004-60_2.png', 'p6004-23_1.jpg', 'p6004-138_1.jpg', 'p6004-218_2.jpg', 'p6004-97_3.png', 'p6004-198_1.jpg', 'p6004-199_1.jpg', 'p6004-209_1.jpg', 'p6004-183_1.jpg', 'p6004-94_2.jpg', 'p6004-172_1.jpg', 'p6004-159_1.jpg', 'p6004-163_1.jpg', 'p6004-243_6.png', 'p6004-53_1.png', 'p6004-203_1.jpg', 'p6004-243_2.png', 'p6004-57_1.png', 'p6004-176_1.jpg', 'p6004-188_1.jpg', 'p6004-192_2.jpg', 'p6004-21_2.jpg', 'p6004-49_1.png', 'p6004-102_1.jpg', 'p6004-156_1.png', 'p6004-95_1.jpg', 'p6004-21_1.jpg', 'p6004-167_1.jpg', 'p6004.xml', 'p6004-133_2.jpg', 'p6004-145_1.jpg', 'p6004-26_2.jpg', 'p6004-134_1.jpg', 'p6004-135_2.jpg', 'p6004-169_1.jpg', 'p6004-138_3.jpg', 'p6004-3_1.jpg', 'p6004-194_1.jpg', 'p6004-141_3.jpg', 'p6004-135_1.jpg', 'p6004-138_2.jpg', 'p6004-155_1.jpg', 'p6004-140_1.jpg', 'p6004-91_1.jpg', 'p6004-156_3.jpg', 'p6004s.html', 'p6004-135_3.jpg', 'p6004-243_3.png', 'p6004.html', 'p6004-136_2.jpg', 'p6004_ind.html', 'p6004-218_1.jpg', 'p6004-191_1.jpg', 'p6004-200_1.jpg', 'p6004-173_1.jpg', 'p6004-94_1.jpg', 'p6004-152_1.jpg', 'p6004-222_2.jpg', 'p6004-178_1.jpg', 'p6004-229_1.jpg', 'p6004-242_3.png', 'p6004-20_1.jpg', 'p6004-170_1.jpg', 'p6004-168_1.jpg', 'p6004-26_1.jpg', 'p6004-222_1.jpg', 'p6004-225_2.jpg', 'p6004-243_1.png', 'p6004-97_2.png', 'p6004-210_2.jpg', 'p6004-49_2.png', 'p6004-215_1.jpg', 'p6004-221_1.jpg', 'p6004-25_1.jpg', 'p6004-242_1.png', 'p6004-133_6.jpg', 'p6004-171_1.jpg', 'p6004-57_2.png', 'p6004-156_2.png', 'p6004-204_1.jpg', 'p6004-243_4.png', 'p6004-220_2.jpg', 'p6004-139_1.jpg', 'p6004-210_1.jpg', 'p6004-242_2.png', 'p6004-205_1.jpg', 'p6004-160_1.jpg', 'p6004-60_1.png', 'p6004-147_1.jpg', 'p6004-48_1.jpg', 'p6004-97_1.jpg', 'p6004-133_3.jpg', 'p6004-133_7.jpg', 'p6004-52_1.jpg', 'p6004-98_1.jpg', 'p6004-273_1.png', 'p6004-211_2.jpg', 'p6004-155_2.jpg', 'p6004-200_2.jpg', 'p6004-99_1.jpg', 'p6004-179_1.jpg', 'p6004-141_4.png', 'p6004-226_1.jpg', 'p6004-133_5.jpg', 'p6004-154_2.jpg', 'p6004-181_1.jpg', 'p6004-61_1.jpg', 'p6004-175_1.jpg', 'p6004-165_1.jpg', 'p6004-141_1.png', 'p6004-51_1.png', 'p6004-136_1.jpg']
```

and all .html and .xml files are successfully removed.  I thought it may be a int vs str thing, but no success...???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are iterating a list, and removing items while iterating, so you are going to skip some items.

Use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) if you want to remove items that match a certain condition:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: not str(x).endswith(("xml","html")), pdfImages))
['00335786-3_1.png', '00335786-1_1.png', '00335786-5_1.png', '00335786-2_1.png', '00335786-4_1.png']
```

Comment: Thank you...did not think about indices changing while removing.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same effect by using list comprehensions.

Try the following:

```
pdfImages = ['00335786_ind.html', '00335786.html', '00335786-3_1.png', '00335786-1_1.png', '00335786.xml', '00335786-5_1.png', '00335786-2_1.png', '00335786s.html', '00335786-4_1.png']
replaced_items = [img for img in pdfImages if not img.endswith(('xml', 'html'))]
print(replaced_items)
```

You will get the following:

```
['00335786-3_1.png', '00335786-1_1.png', '00335786-5_1.png', '00335786-2_1.png', '00335786-4_1.png']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are looping through a list and simultaneously removing its elements, due to which the current item index doesnt point to the desired one.

Following works -

```
import os
pdfImages = os.listdir("temp")

pdfImages = [item for item in pdfImages if not str(item).endswith(("xml", "html"))]

print "pdfImages = " + str(pdfImages)
```